# Access shared folder from behind Tomato VPN

Tags: networking, router, vpn, subnet, tomato

This is my setup:
(192.168.1.254)Modem->(192.168.1.1)Tomato(via cabel)->(192.168.1.148)PC(Shared folders).
I was able to setup vpn for 10.8.0.0 and with 255.255.255.0, but only problem was, that my other PC which have 192.168.1.148 was not seeing over VPN. So when i tried to change VPN address to 192.168.1.2 and with 255.255.255.0 it was giving me error:`server directive network/netmask combination is invalid`.

How can I switch to 192.168.1.2 subnet ?

Comment: so wait, the network between your Modem and your routers WAN is 192.168.1.x/24 and the LAN inside the router is also on 192.168.1.x/24?

Comment: yes, but even if i changed router & vpn to 192.168.0.1 it's the same result